# How to disable autosave feature on IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

env: IDEA-14.0.2, kubuntu14.10 x64

Yesterday I use IDEA to learn source from Spark. When discussing with my partner, I write serval lines directly to the source, then I closed the IDEA without ctrl+S

Today when I open the project I found that those little changes still exist and make the source very dirty (and bit hard to remove them since they are everywhere). I assume that there's a autosave feature the avoid close without saving by incident.

how to close that on certain project? or do it globally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently it can't be disabled. There are a few open issues in the IntelliJ's YouTrack, for instance [IDEABKL-6460](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6460). There is a long discussion in this issue, but from comments like this:

> Auto-saving is built in very deeply and many IDE features just won't
>   work without it (e.g. compilation, running, etc). For reverting
>   unwanted changes there's VCS, Local History and Undo.
>
> Currently we don't plan to add a possibility to disable auto-save.

it seems that implementing this feature isn't planned and even if it was it would be probably difficult. But you can leave a comment and vote for the issue because the more people request this feature the more probable it is that it will get actually implemented sometime in the future.

Comment: If you are using source control (and you probably should), local changes should never be a problem - just revert them as needed.

Comment: IntelliJ also has local history, so this should work even when editing some file that is not under version control (https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/local_history.html)

Comment: There is also discussion on this feature in the document https://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-191 My recommendation is to get use to it and to using the local history as needed to roll back. They will not change this. Once you get use to the auto save, you end up wondering how you ever lived without it. (I fought it when I first started using IDEA 11 years ago. Now, I love it.)